# How to use rake with rake tasks outside rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I think Rails is very heavy and I'm taking pieces out of my projects and making them standalone. My library of tasks, I would like it to work outside Rails. So there is no application and no config/application.rb, only the lib/ folder that defines tasks. How should I structure my rakefile to include all the tasks defined in `lib/tasks/*rake`? My non-working attempt is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env/rake
d = Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/src/tasks/*.rake" ]
d.each do |file|
  require "tasks/"+ File.basename(file, File.extname(file))
end
```

The invocation is something like `bundle exec rake -T -Isrc`

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your rake file

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/src/tasks/*.rake" ].each{ |rake_file| load rake_file }
```